# tSQL Error: Msg 8120, Level 16 on simple AdventureWorks 2008 R2 Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Attempting to ramp up on tSql and doing a simple, or what I believe to be a simple statement. This example came out of Microsoft's Virtural Acdamey class "Querying Microsoft Sql Server 2012 Database. This is the query:

```
Use AdventureWorks
    SELECT SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE (CustomerID = 29974)
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY SalesPersonID, OrderYear
```

This is the error msg
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thanks guys. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `SalesOrderID` is in `select` and `SalesPersonID` is `group by` thats why

Comment: Ah Thanks. Didn't even think to look for that.  This level of sql is new to me. Thank you again. If you would post it as an answer I would be very happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the required `column` and use it in `group by`

```
SELECT SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE (CustomerID = 29974)
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY SalesPersonID, OrderYear
```

Comment: Thanks NoDisplayName and thanks to Andy on the Group clause statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are going for, but it looks like you are trying to group on the sales person.  If so you should change

SELECT *SalesOrderID*, YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE (CustomerID = 29974)
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY SalesPersonID, OrderYear

to

SELECT **SalesPersonID**, YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE (CustomerID = 29974)
    GROUP BY SalesPersonID, YEAR(OrderDate)
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY SalesPersonID, OrderYear

If you use the Group clause you need to do what the error message indicates and add the column in the select tot the group clause or an change it to an aggregate function in the select.  Since you said you are just learning SQL, these are some good topics to look into.  Aggregation in SQL and grouping.

Comment: NoDisplayName hit it. It might have been a very stupid mistake on my part if it wasn't for how new I'm to this. Thanks Andy. I knew I could count on you guys to help me get going.

Comment: comment on Group clause is very useful. Thanks. I will be looking into that.

Comment: BTW say hi to the rockies for me. I miss them.

Comment: Good golly. I'm starting to understand how SQl is put together. It's parsed so much differently than any procedural language I've work with in the past 20 years. taking a quick glance at tsql100 parser shed some light on that!!!!